# Load data from txt with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, file-io

I am loading a txt file containig a mix of float and string data. I want to store them in an array where I can access each element. Now I am just doing

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('output_list.txt', header = None)
print data
```

Each line in the input file looks like the following:

```
 1 0 2000.0 70.2836942112 1347.28369421 /file_address.txt
```

Now the data are imported as a unique column. How can I divide it, so to store different elements separately (so I can call `data[i,j]`)? And how can I define a header?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can do as:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file_location\filename.txt', delimiter = "\t")
```

(like, df = pd.read_csv('F:\Desktop\ds\text.txt', delimiter = "\t")

Answer (score 354):

You can use:

```
data = pd.read_csv('output_list.txt', sep=" ", header=None)
data.columns = ["a", "b", "c", "etc."]
```

Add `sep=" "` in your code, leaving a blank space between the quotes. So pandas can detect spaces between values and sort in columns. Data columns is for naming your columns.

Comment: Thanks! How can I access an element of the table?

Comment: if you want to call a column use data.a if you named the column "a".

Comment: Or if you want to call a single row you can use data.a[1] (this example calls the first row of the column)

Answer (score 152):

I'd like to add to the above answers, you could directly use

```
df = pd.read_fwf('output_list.txt')
```

fwf stands for fixed width formatted lines.

Comment: thank you! It solved my long time pending problem.

Comment: This is wrong! In a very subtle way that created lots of headaches for me. As described in the pandas docs, "String value ‘infer’ can be used to instruct the parser to try detecting the column specifications from the first 100 rows of the data which are not being skipped via skiprows (default=’infer’)." So basically, any data that is longer than the longest data in your first 100 rows will be silently truncated!

Comment: Unless your data is truly fixed-width (I see no indication of this in the question), use the most upvoted answer.

Answer (score 55):

@Pietrovismara's solution is correct but I'd just like to add: rather than having a separate line to add column names, it's possible to do this from pd.read_csv.

```
df = pd.read_csv('output_list.txt', sep=" ", header=None, names=["a", "b", "c"])
```

Answer (score 34):

you can use this

```
import pandas as pd
dataset=pd.read_csv("filepath.txt",delimiter="\t")
```

Comment: As you can see from this answer, 'sep' and 'delimeter' are the same :)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49533103

Answer (score 29):

If you don't have an index assigned to the data and you are not sure what the spacing is, you can use to let pandas assign an index and look for multiple spaces.

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.txt', delimiter= '\s+', index_col=False)
```

Comment: Equivalently you can specify the more verbose argument `delim_whitespace=True` instead of the `'\s+'` delimiter

Answer (score 11):

If you want to load the txt file with specified column name, you can use the code below. It worked for me.

```
import pandas as pd    
data = pd.read_csv('file_name.txt', sep = "\t", names = ['column1_name','column2_name', 'column3_name'])
```

Answer (score 8):

Based on the latest changes in pandas, you can use, read_csv , read_table is deprecated:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv("file.txt", sep = "\t")
```

Answer (score 7):

You can import the text file using the read_table command as so:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_table('output_list.txt',header=None)
```

Preprocessing will need to be done after loading

Answer (score 3):

You can use it which is most helpful.

```
df = pd.read_csv(('data.txt'), sep="\t", skiprows=[0,1], names=['FromNode','ToNode'])
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually take a look at the data first or just try to import it and do data.head(), if you see that the columns are separated with \t then you should specify `sep="\t"` otherwise, `sep = " "`.

```
import pandas as pd     
data = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep=" ", header=None)
```

Comment: Carefully adding "header=None" and adding an additional row with the max number of columns,  you will get errors like "pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected N fields in line M" very hard to understand why. Removing "header=None"  fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main functions given on this page (`read_csv` and `read_fwf`) but none of the answers explain when to use each one. In short, `read_csv` reads delimited files whereas `read_fwf` reads fixed width files.

#### `read_csv`

If your text file is similar to the following (note that each column is separated from one another by a single space character `' '`):

```
0 1.5 first 100
1 .5 thirteenth 20
2 3.0 last 3000
```

then it is a space-delimited file, so you should use `read_csv`.

```py
df = pd.read_csv('my_data.txt', header=None, sep=' ')
```

Note that the delimiter doesn't have to be a space character; in fact, comma (`','`) is the most common one (i.e. CSV).

#### `read_fwf`

If your text file is similar to the following:

```
0 1.5      first  100
1  .5 thirteenth   20
2 3.0       last 3000
```

then it is a fixed-width file, so you should use `read_fwf`.

```py
df = pd.read_fwf('my_data.txt', header=None)

# can also explicitly pass column widths instead of letting pandas infer them
df = pd.read_fwf('my_data.txt', header=None, widths=[2, 3, 11, 5])
```

You can pass a regex separator to read this file format using `read_csv` as well:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('my_data.txt', header=None, sep=' +')
```

But doing so, you would have to fall back to the python engine which could make the file reading much slower.