# What is the difference between `sep` and `delimiter` attributes in pandas.read_csv() method?

Tags: python, pandas, delimiter

What is the difference between `sep` and `delimiter` attributes in `pandas.read_csv()` method?

Also what is the situation when I would choose one over the other?

In documentation I read something about Python builtin sniffer tool, also in delimiter, it says *alternative argument name for sep*, then why cant we have only one attribute?

Comment: [Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) is always worth reading

Comment: Yes I read that but I couldn't understand the reason for having two attributes which do the same thing.

Comment: For those who are interested: the reason of such separation is sought therein: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50103582/3393574

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Confirmation that they are the same thing can be found in the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.0.2/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py#L1961):

```
# Alias sep -> delimiter.
if delimiter is None:
    delimiter = sep
```

I agree with the other answer that it is best to stick to `sep`. It seems to be more commonly used, and it is more consistent with other functions such as [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), which does not accept `delimiter`, only `sep`.

Comment: and it is less typing :)

Comment: If anyone likes to use `delim_whitespace=True` like me, it is easily replaceable with `sep="\s+"`.. also less keystrokes

Answer (score 5):

They're the same thing. See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

I assume one is for backwards compatibility. I'd just use `sep`, it's what I see the most.