# Why do 'sep' and 'delimiter' arguments exist together in read_csv and read_table of pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

[What is the difference between `sep` and `delimiter` attributes in pandas.read_csv() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49532873/what-is-the-difference-between-sep-and-delimiter-attributes-in-pandas-read-c) sought an answer for the differences between `sep` and `delimiter` arguments of `read_csv` function of `pandas`.

The [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49533103/3393574) and the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html) clearly stated that `sep` and `delimiter` are the same.

This separation does not exist in [read_fwf](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html) and [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to name but a few; yet exists in [read_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html).

Nevertheless, none of the above explained **why** this separation is present and why it is needed. Could you please tell us what is the use of separating `sep` and `delimiter` for `read_csv` and `read_table`?

Comment: Unless you are looking for something like mailing list posts or similar, I don't really understand what the purpose of your question is.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see how your question is different from the other where the answer is "backward compatibility". I've closed your question for now.

Comment: Just a thought: Maybe sep was added in the beginning and delimiter was added to be more consistent with other libraries. I looked back in the docs and it looks like both have existed for quite some time: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.7.0/io.html

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I kindly disagree with you as 'what' and 'why' are two different and legitimate questions.

Comment: Why = "backward compatibility", also there in the other question's answer.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ 'I assume one is for backwards compatibility.' This is only a speculation! The answer to that question was given just above this commentary. I do not want to believe if you deem an 'answer' and a 'speculation' as the same notions.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The purpose of this question was to seek a reason why such a separation was made. I was not looking for their differences as the previous question sought. I would like to kindly state that the rationale of closing this question is arbitrary in my humble opinion. Critical thinking clearly differentiates 'why' and 'what' questions.