# Pandas read_csv with delimiter ';' not working on PyCharm but working on Jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I have a question concerning the use of pandas in PyCharm. If I execute the following code in jupyter it works perfectly well but when I do the same thing in PyCharm the file somehow does not get parsed correctly. I mean the columns are not separated correctly.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_csv("testdaten.csv", delimiter=";")
print(file)
```

[image]

[image]

What can I do?

Here's what I get in jupyter:

[image]

Comment: Please post what output you are getting in 'Anaconda' (I don't know what you are trying to say by using Anaconda, maybe it's Jupyter or Spyder). Also, try using sep intead of delimiter.

Comment: Thanks, I meant jupyter of course. It doesnt make any difference whether I use delim=";" or sep=";" in the read_csv()-Method. It looks as if the columns are not separated correctly, so I cannot print out `file['name']` either.

Comment: That's very peculiar. I'll try implementing this and get back ASAP.

Comment: It's working on my system.

Comment: @D.Studer, what if you use `file = pd.read_csv("testdaten.csv",  sep=";")` rather `delimiter`  ?

Comment: Works with `delimiter` as well. Maybe this is a version issue of pandas. I think the second-last bug fix of (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#id213) refers to the problem.

Comment: Yes, but worth to [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49532873/what-is-the-difference-between-sep-and-delimiter-attributes-in-pandas-read-c)

Comment: I've tried "sep" only, "delimiter" only or both together. It doesn't make a difference. I'm using Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (x86_64) and PyCharm (Community Version) 2018.3

Answer (score 0):

It works for me using `sep` over `delimiter` :

```
file = pd.read_csv("testdaten.csv", sep=";")
```

It seems to be more commonly used, and it is more consistent with other functions such as `to_csv`, which does not accept delimiter, only `sep`.

look at the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/parsers.py)

also [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

> sep : str, default ‘,’
>
> Delimiter to use. If sep is None, the C engine cannot automatically
>   detect the separator, but the Python parsing engine can, meaning the
>   latter will be used and automatically detect the separator by Python’s
>   builtin sniffer tool, csv.Sniffer. In addition, separators longer than
>   1 character and different from '\s+' will be interpreted as regular
>   expressions and will also force the use of the Python parsing engine.
>   Note that regex delimiters are prone to ignoring quoted data. Regex
>   example: '\r\t'
>
> delimiter : str, default None
>
> Alternative argument name for sep.