# Pandas read TSV wrong columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I read these two TSV files from Pandas:

```
train = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/loretoparisi/bert_text_classifier/master/data/imdb_kaggle/train.tsv', sep="\t", delimiter="\n", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, engine="python", quotechar='"', encoding="utf-8")
test = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/loretoparisi/bert_text_classifier/master/data/imdb_kaggle/test.tsv', sep="\t", delimiter="\n", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, engine="python", quotechar='"', encoding="utf-8")
```

but I get a shape of `(N,1)` instead of `(N,3)`

```
(156060, 1) (66292, 1)
PhraseId\tSentenceId\tPhrase
0   156061\t8545\tAn intermittently pleasing but m...
1   156062\t8545\tAn intermittently pleasing but m...
2   156063\t8545\tAn
3   156064\t8545\tintermittently pleasing but most...
4   156065\t8545\tintermittently pleasing but most...
```

[The](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/loretoparisi/bert_text_classifier/master/data/imdb_kaggle/test.tsv) raw file is like

```
PhraseId    SentenceId  Phrase
156061  8545    An intermittently pleasing but mostly routine effort .
156062  8545    An intermittently pleasing but mostly routine effort
156063  8545    An
156064  8545    intermittently pleasing but mostly routine effort
156065  8545    intermittently pleasing but mostly routine
156066  8545    intermittently pleasing but
156067  8545    intermittently pleasing
156068  8545    intermittently
156069  8545    pleasing
```

Assumed that I have passed already the separator `sep='\t'`, why `read_csv` fails?

Comment: Try removing `delimeter='\n'`. I think you should just need `pd.read_csv('file.tsv', '\t')`

Comment: Simply `pd.read_csv('train.tsv', sep='\t')` works for me.

Comment: @MichaelSilverstein :D cannot believe was that easy, but why.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49532873/what-is-the-difference-between-sep-and-delimiter-attributes-in-pandas-read-c) an explanation. In short, they are alias of one another.

Comment: Because `delimiter` is just an "alias" for `sep`. So when you provide both it may be looking to split on `\n` instead of `\t` as explained in the docs https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html