# How to fix "ImportError: cannot import name 'StringIO'"

Tags: python, stringio, pandas-datareader

python version is 3.6.6 and pandas_datareader version is 0.7.0

when i import pandas_datareader, an error occurs like below.

```
C:\PycharmProjects\Demo\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/PycharmProjects/Demo/stock.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PycharmProjects/Demo/stock.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pandas_datareader as wb
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\Demo\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .data import (DataReader, Options, get_components_yahoo,
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\Demo\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas_datareader.av.forex import AVForexReader
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\Demo\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\av\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pandas_datareader.base import _BaseReader
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\Demo\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import StringIO, bytes_to_str
ImportError: cannot import name 'StringIO'
```

can somebody help me?

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have created a module named `pandas.compat` right?

Comment: i happened to know that it's a matter of python version.
3.5.x works well. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you found a solution to this, then you should add it as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is pandas 0.25.0 has removed pandas.compat. So go back to 0.24.2

```
pip install "pandas<0.25.0"
```

or

```
pipenv install "pandas<0.25.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue with Python3.6 and Python3.7

Downgraded, and it works fine on Python2.7
Also, saw a comment above that Python3.5 works.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not clear from the discussion here, I add it as an answer. The [`StringIO` is available from io](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html), [not from `pandas.compat` anymore](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/25997). Although my problem was a bit different but the source of the error & the error message are same in my case. As of March 2023, this works:

```
import pandas
# from pandas.compat import StringIO #deprecated
from io import StringIO

text = '''

Scenario        Accuracy (%)            Loss (1012) Underestimated Jobs (%)
        RAM HDD Walltime        RAM HDD Walltime
1   Original    63.4    27.8    52.5    114.9   40.9    17.2    20.2
2   User    62.6    27.9    13.3    589.0   1.0 1.0 1.0
'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(ETP), sep='\t')
df
```

[image]