# divide the rows values of the text files

Tags: linux, shell, for-loop, awk

i have two text files `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`. Both the files contain same number of rows and columns and i want to divide all rows of file1.txt with file2.txt and my expected output is depicted below.NB: in output file the  the string ?-er modes will be replaced by `v-er modes`.I hope some expert will help me finding my output.Thanks in advance.

file1.txt

```
layer  1     s-er modes          u = -15.0
2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98
2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98
2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98

layer  2     s-er modes          u =   0.0
2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98
2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98
2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98

layer  3     s-er modes          u =   10.0
2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98
2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98
2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98
```

file2.txt

```
layer  1     m-er modes          u = -15.0
2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98
2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98
2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98

layer  2     m-er modes          u =   0.0
2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98
2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98
2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98

layer  3     m-er modes          u =  10.0
2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98
2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98
2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98   2.98
```

output

```
layer  1     v-er modes          u = -15.0
1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00
1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00
1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00

layer  2     v-er modes          u =   0.0
1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00
1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00
1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00

layer  3     v-er modes          u =   10.0
1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00
1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00
1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00
```

Comment: Are you files split by `\t`?

Comment: have you read them into pandas? if so `df1.div(df2)` should do the trick (if the index / columns are aligned as you have said) what have you tried so far?

Comment: what part is confusing?

Comment: [How to load data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546739/load-data-from-txt-with-pandas). Just change `sep='   '` to match your files

Comment: `df1 = pd.read_csv(your_file,sep='\t')` or change `sep=' \s+` if its space delimited

Comment: @Manakin can u please show some solution

Comment: What should be output when a cell in file2.tx is `0`?

Comment: Zero it should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="   " }
/^layer/ || !NF {
    if (NR != FNR) {
        gsub(/m-er/,"v-er")
        print
    }
    next
}
NR==FNR {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        f[FNR,i] = $i
    }
    next
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        printf "%.02f%s", ($i ? f[FNR,i] / $i : 0), (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1.txt file2.txt
layer  1     v-er modes          u = -15.0
1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00
1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00
1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00

layer  2     v-er modes          u =   0.0
1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00
1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00
1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00

layer  3     v-er modes          u =  10.0
1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00
1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00
1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00
```