# How to obtain the names of N highest scorers given a large dataset of student scores?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, bigdata, data-science

I have a .txt file containing a large dataset (more than 90 million entries) in the following format:

| Score | Student Name |
| --- | --- |
| 35 | Lily |
| 45 | Rex |
| 20 | Cameron |
| 45 | Max |
| 20 | Jasmin |

In the text file, the score and the name are separated by 2 spaces and has one score-name entry per line

This .txt file cannot be loaded into the memory at a time.

How to obtain the first N highest scorers in python ?
**Note: the value of N can be extremely large**

Example:
So when N=2,

the output should be :
Rex
Max

Is there a way in python to directly obtain the first N scorers without saving the whole data again in another file format ?

Which way is more efficient ?
1.) read score entries one by one and save/update the largest N score entries?
2.) move all data to pandas dataframes and use nlargest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read the text file into a pandas [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) the answer to that is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546739/load-data-from-txt-with-pandas).
Then you can try the following:
you can try using pandas [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html). For example you can do:

```
largest = df.nlargest(n,'score')['Student Name']
```

You can also convert the `score` column to a Numpy array and use [`argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html)

```
import numpy as np
largest = df.iloc[np.argsort(-df['score'])[:n]]['Student Name']
```

Additionally you can try sorting the DataFrame and take the top n rows like so:

```
largest = df.sort_values('score', ascending=False).iloc[:n]['Student Name']
```

Here is the comparison of runtime for a DataFrame with 100 million records and `n=1000000`

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100000000, 2)),  columns=['score', 'Student Name'])
 n = 1000000
 start = time()
 temp = df.nlargest(n, 'score')['Student Name']
 print(time() - start)

 start = time()
 temp2 = df.iloc[np.argsort(-df['score'])[:n]]['Student Name']
 print(time() - start)

 start = time()
 temp3 = df.sort_values('score', ascending=False).iloc[:n]['Student Name']
 print(time() - start)
```

Resluts:

```
3.5889642238616943
13.237002849578857
19.69099760055542
```

So the most efficient way would be to use `nlargest`

Comment: Since, the whole datatset cannot be fit into the memory, so is it better to first convert the text file data into pandas dataframes and use nlargest, or is there a way to do it directly ?

Comment: `pandas` is not a file format but a python Object, please provide more information about the problem you are having, what you have tried and where did you encounter trouble.

Comment: Also, since there are only 1 million entries in your text file they should easily be uploaded to a pandas DataFrame

Comment: One last thing, if want an explanation on how to parse the .txt file into a pandas DataFrame please provide more information as to how it is saved

Comment: I updated the question, I actually have more than 90 million entries and they dont fit in my memory

Comment: In the text file there is one entry per line, in each line the score comes first and the name is second (separated by 2 spaces)

Comment: As you can see from my example, using nlargest on a DataFrame if 100 million rows and n is 1 million returned results in 3 seconds in my machine. So I would still recommend using it.

Comment: ok thank you very much, could you also explain how to parse the txt file to a DataFrame

Comment: I added a link to a question that explains it.
If my explanation answered your question please mark it as accepted.

Comment: What if the input data is given as stdin (data is in the same format), can you tell me how to parse such an input to a DataFrame ?

Comment: This requires a different question as it is not relevant here. please post a different question.