# How to split 1 line of data into multiple columns with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, data-storage

I am currently working with CAN-Bus data that outputs everything into 1 column, multiple rows. The way the code works is by sending and receiving msg to a car's Can-bus network to receive real-time data. The received data is stored in a variable "response" which when printed out, gives the following data.

```
Timestamp: 1646874440.563719        ID: 0060    S Rx                DL:  8    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1646874440.563959        ID: 0090    S Rx                DL:  8    00 00 c2 00 61 83 00 00     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1646874440.564195        ID: 00c0    S Rx                DL:  8    00 2d 61 27 50 00 39 f3     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1646874440.565563        ID: 0010    S Rx                DL:  8    0d e7 00 00 00 00 81 47     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1646874440.566430        ID: 00c8    S Rx                DL:  8    cb 87 3e f1 10 38 c6 02     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1646874440.567062        ID: 0160    S Rx                DL:  8    55 ff 00 00 57 23 ed ff     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1646874440.567308        ID: 0180    S Rx                DL:  8    03 00 0d f8 17 fe f0 00     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1646874440.567558        ID: 0190    S Rx                DL:  8    80 00 80 00 80 00 80 00     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1646874440.567802        ID: 01c0    S Rx                DL:  8    f7 c0 00 00 80 00 00 00     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1646874440.568048        ID: 01d0    S Rx                DL:  8    a8 ff ff 00 00 00 00 00     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1646874440.568282        ID: 01e0    S Rx                DL:  8    58 e1 de 05 00 00 fd 23     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1646874440.568531        ID: 0210    S Rx                DL:  8    00 00 00 00 f2 9b 00 00     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1646874440.568772        ID: 00a0    S Rx                DL:  8    01 7b 29 f3 00 00 7f fe     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1646874440.569017        ID: 0213    S Rx                DL:  8    00 f2 00 00 0f ff df ff     Channel: can0
```

I am trying to look for a way to separate this data into separate "Timestamp" "ID" "DL" "Channel" columns and separate ones for each hex value. I need them separated in order to sort through and get the codes and values needed for different display data (Ex. RPM, Steering angle). This data is set to update every 1/10 of a second however it can increase, I don't know if a system should be put in place to deleted old data after a certain amount of time so it doesn't fill up the data storage.

I am rather new to python indices and data logging so anything would help.

Thank you for your time!

Code I am currently testing with (Clarifications in the comments).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table("CB.txt" , delimiter=" ")
df = df.str.split(" ", 1, expand = True)
print(df)
```

Comment: Did you try s.split('        ')?

Comment: @Can Sucuoglu By s.split, do you mean s. being the variable "response". For a bit of clarification, the code that I use to get the data only works when connected to a car. I saved the data into a CSV file called "CB.csv" and the test code I'm working with has been added to the post above. My goal is to get it working all in one code, and not need to print to a CSV file and use another code to read from it. I am very new to python coding so it's going to have to be dumbed down quite a bit unfortunately.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21546823/5954452

Comment: @BlackFox Thank you for the link, when writing the code, it gives me the following error "Length mismatch: Expected axis has 51 elements, new values have 4 elements
" I only did the data.columns "a","b","c","d" which explains the 4 elements. It seems to make a column for each character.

Comment: Quick update, the white spaces between timestamp and ID and other parts are taking up elements, I guess I can either drop the columns or is there a way to delete whitespace before putting them in individual columns?

Comment: Sounds like a new post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I did end up finding a solution. The biggest problem is that the white spaces count as an element in a table so you have to make a column for the white space and deleted the column right after.

The following code worked for me.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table("CB.txt", sep=" ", header=None)
df.columns = ["a","Timestamp","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","ID","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","fag","9","10","11","B0","B1","B2","B3","B4","B5","B6","B7","20","21","22","23","24","Channel"]
df = df.drop(columns=['a','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','1','2','3','4','5','6','fag','7','9','10','11','20','21','22','23','24'])
```

An error will appear stating the number of elements needed, so this list will change according to what you need. This is definitely not the best way to do this, but its a solution non the less.