# Pure Pandas approach to converting data in a text file into a table

Tags: python, pandas, text-files

I am looking to convert data in a textile into a table (data frame) using just methods from Pandas.

### Textfile

```bash
00100
11110
10110
10111
10101
01111
00111
11100
10000
11001
00010
01010
```

### Table/Dataframe format

```bash
    0  1  2  3  4
0   0  0  1  0  0
1   1  1  1  1  0
2   1  0  1  1  0
3   1  0  1  1  1
4   1  0  1  0  1
5   0  1  1  1  1
6   0  0  1  1  1
7   1  1  1  0  0
8   1  0  0  0  0
9   1  1  0  0  1
10  0  0  0  1  0
11  0  1  0  1  0
```

---

### My approach

The only way I could think of doing it was to use some Python code to read the file into a 2D list of characters and then convert that to a data frame:

```py
with open("data.txt") as f:
        # Removes newline character and splits binary string into individual character bits
        binary = [list(line.strip()) for line in f]

df = pd.DataFrame(binary, dtype="object")  # 2D list into pd dataframe
```

Although this works, I would like to know if this could have been done using Pandas with the read_csv() method

Comment: You can look at this topic.
[Load data from .txt with Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546739/load-data-from-txt-with-pandas)
I think it might answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work in your case:

```
df = pd.read_fwf('untitled.txt', widths=[1,1,1,1,1], header=None)
print(df)
```

Result:

```
    0  1  2  3  4
0   0  0  1  0  0
1   1  1  1  1  0
2   1  0  1  1  0
3   1  0  1  1  1
4   1  0  1  0  1
5   0  1  1  1  1
6   0  0  1  1  1
7   1  1  1  0  0
8   1  0  0  0  0
9   1  1  0  0  1
10  0  0  0  1  0
11  0  1  0  1  0
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Just fixed the code and added "header=None".

Comment: And if I wanted to generalise to n columns, I would just do `df = pd.read_fwf('untitled.txt', widths=[1]*num_cols, header=None)`.

Comment: Thanks for showing a one-liner approach. Pandas genuinely seems to have methods that do nearly everything :)

Answer (score 1):

Below code can help. **Will also work with txt file**

```
df = pd.read_csv('Book2.csv',header=None, dtype='str') #read file
df = df[0].astype('str').str.split('',expand=True) #split column
df[df.columns[1:-1]] #print df after removing first & last empty column
```

Output will look like this
[image]

Comment: Nice, `df[df.columns[1:-1]]` can be `df.iloc[:, 1:-1]`

Comment: Yeah, it will be more appropriate. Will use this syntax in future. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you dropping the first and last columns? Also, I noticed that starts the index from 1, whereas I wanted it from 0, which needs a couple more lines of code to get to the desired output. @rene showed that read_fwf does all this in one line :)